# Swift: Segue to next screen when successfully login

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I am trying to:
 1. Login 
 2. Parse the response 
 3. print the response 
 4. segue to next screen

**Code**

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, responseData, error) -> Void in
    if let response = responseData as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        statusCode = response.statusCode
        print("Response code: \(statusCode)")
    }

    do {
        if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary {
            if let data = json["data"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let user = data["user"] as? NSDictionary {
                    self.loggedUser = User(resp: user)
                    self.printData(self.loggedUser!)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
        err = error
    }

    if(statusCode != 200) {
        let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
    } else {
        //print("Everything Looks good: \(responseData)")
        self.shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier("showHomeController", sender: self)
    }
}

private func printData(user: User) {
    let id = user.id as Int
    print("id: \(id)")
    print("Parent: \(loggedUser?.userType)")
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showHomeController" {
        let homeViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! HomeViewController
        homeViewController.user = self.loggedUser
    }
}
```

It does not work in the same order. Code is segueing to next screen before parsing the data.
Why is this happening?

Comment: What exactly do you mean that the code is segueing before parsing? Do you mean that the segue occurs before the data printed by `printData()` is displayed in the console, or do you mean that the segue is actually performed before `JSONObjectWithData()` returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier with performSegueWithIdentifier